# Dynamically add ManyToMany relationship to Django objects

Tags: python, django, dynamic

My Company class have multiple M2M relationship with itself

class Company(models.Model):

```
divisions = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, related_name="parent_companies")
parents = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, related_name="divisions_companies")
comp = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, related_name="comp")
friends = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, related_name="friends")
```

I would like to be able to dynamically add M2M relationship like this, but it obviously does not work. Is there a way to do it dynamically ?

```
                    company, was_created = Company.objects.get_or_create(name=info)
                    setattr(self,key, company)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it. Simply have to pass a list instead..

```
 company, was_created = Company.objects.get_or_create(name=info)
                        setattr(self,key, [company,])
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is for adding M2M is `field.add(obj_pk or obj)`

```
company, was_created = Company.objects.get_or_create(name=info)
self.comp.add(company)
```

Comment: that's when you know the field name. Idea here is to do it dynamically. But I found it, just have to passa list instead of one alement

Comment: I see. PS: accept your own answer so we know this has been solved :)

Comment: I will but i need to wait 2 days ;-)